# In Oracle, how do I pivot data into multiple columns?

Tags: oracle, pivot, row-number, rownum

I have the following test table and I need to get the following result table. I've tried a pivot, but that only seems to work when you have a descriptor and a value. In this case, we just have a value. Some site_id's might only have 1 value, but some can have up to 3 other site_id_alt's. There are over 2800 unique site_id's, so manually coding them into a pivot function an option.

I was thinking some sort of partition might work, but no idea where to start with that.

```
drop table site_id_cd_test;
create table site_id_cd_test
 (
  site_id_alt VARCHAR(30),
  site_id VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into site_id_cd_test values('1A1-071', '1A1-071');
insert into site_id_cd_test values('1A1-071O', '1A1-071');
insert into site_id_cd_test values('030256', '1A1-071');
insert into site_id_cd_test values('04268384', '1A1-071');
insert into site_id_cd_test values('04268383', '1A1-072');


drop table site_id_cd_result;
create table site_id_cd_result
 (
  site_id VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_01 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_02 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_03 VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into site_id_cd_result values('1A1-071', '1A1-071O', '030256', '04268384' );
insert into site_id_cd_result values('1A1-072', '04268383', NULL, NULL);
```

EDIT 9_19_19:

After feedback from @MT0, we get about 90% of the way there (it pivots well on row number). When the site_id matches the site_id_alt, then it adds those as a new row (as shown below in an example table). Ideally we would like to have the matching site_id and site_id_alt in the same row with the other values.

Summary of the below example tables:

**site_id_cd_result** is the resulting table when running with the row number pivoting

**site_id_cd_result_02** is the resulting table when using site_id <> site_id_alt

```
drop table site_id_cd_result;

create table site_id_cd_result
 (
  site_id VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_01 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_02 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_03 VARCHAR(30),
 site_id_alt_04 VARCHAR(30)

);

insert into site_id_cd_result values('1A1-071', '1A1-071', NULL, NULL, NULL);
insert into site_id_cd_result values('1A1-071', NULL, '040777', '04253626', '1A1-071O');
insert into site_id_cd_result values('1A1-072', '04268383', '123546', NULL, NULL);


drop table site_id_cd_result_02;

create table site_id_cd_result_02
 (
  site_id VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_01 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_02 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_03 VARCHAR(30),
 site_id_alt_04 VARCHAR(30)

);

insert into site_id_cd_result_02 values('1A1-071', '040777', '04253626', '1A1-071O', NULL);
insert into site_id_cd_result_02 values('1A1-072', '04268383', '123546', NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Sample I/O would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to give each `SITE_ID_ALT` a column number for each `SITE_ID` and then you can `PIVOT` on that:

**Query**:

```sql
INSERT INTO site_id_cd_result ( site_id, site_id_alt_01, site_id_alt_02, site_id_alt_03 )
SELECT site_id,
       site_id_alt_01,
       site_id_alt_02,
       site_id_alt_03
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   site_id_cd_test t
  -- WHERE site_id <> site_id_alt    -- If you don't want the matching value
)
PIVOT ( MAX( site_id_alt ) FOR rn IN (
  1 AS site_id_alt_01,
  2 AS site_id_alt_02,
  3 AS site_id_alt_03
) )
```

**Result**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM site_id_cd_result;
```

> ```
> SITE_ID | SITE_ID_ALT_01 | SITE_ID_ALT_02 | SITE_ID_ALT_03
> :------ | :------------- | :------------- | :-------------
> 1A1-071 | 1A1-071        | 1A1-071O       | 030256        
> 1A1-072 | 04268383       | null           | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=423725fb9e61cff35f614906c590ec7f)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit klugey, but it has the advantage of working:

```
WITH cteAgg AS (SELECT SITE_ID,
                       LISTAGG(SITE_ID_ALT, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SITE_ID_ALT) ALTS
                  FROM SITE_ID_CD_TEST
                  GROUP BY SITE_ID)
SELECT SITE_ID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 1) AS ALT1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 2) AS ALT2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 3) AS ALT3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 4) AS ALT4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 5) AS ALT5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 6) AS ALT6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 7) AS ALT7,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 8) AS ALT8,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 9) AS ALT9,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ALTS, '[^|]+', 1, 10) AS ALT10
  FROM cteAgg;
```

Basically, you LISTAGG all the alternates into a big string, then bust the substrings out into individual fields. Limitations are that the total length of the alternates+separators can't be more than the maximum allowed size of a VARCHAR2 in your version-of-choice. Still, I've seen (and written :-) worse.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=577f749afc9714469d022e8733a69e26)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out! A colleague helped me and we came up with using the MAX function along with a GROUP BY on site_id to select the values so that there is just one row of data with no nulls at the beginning. There might be another way to do this, but this works for now. This does require making two tables, but I was unable to condense them into one.

```
DROP TABLE site_id_cd_result;

CREATE TABLE site_id_cd_result
 (
  site_id VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_01 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_02 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_03 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_04 VARCHAR(30),
  site_id_alt_05 VARCHAR(30)
);


INSERT INTO site_id_cd_result (
site_id, site_id_alt_01, site_id_alt_02, site_id_alt_03, site_id_alt_04, site_id_alt_05)
SELECT site_id,
      site_id_alt_01,
      site_id_alt_02,
      site_id_alt_03,
      site_id_alt_04,
      site_id_alt_05
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   site_id_cd t
)
PIVOT ( MAX( site_id_alt ) FOR rn IN (
  1 AS site_id_alt_01,
  2 AS site_id_alt_02,
  3 AS site_id_alt_03,
  4 AS site_id_alt_04,
  5 AS site_id_alt_05,
  6 AS site_id_alt_06
) )
;


DROP TABLE site_id_cd_result_02;

CREATE TABLE site_id_cd_result_02 AS
SELECT site_id, MAX(site_id_alt_01) AS site_id_alt_01, MAX(site_id_alt_02) AS site_id_alt_02, MAX(site_id_alt_03) AS site_id_alt_03, 
       MAX(site_id_alt_04) AS site_id_alt_04, MAX(site_id_alt_05) AS site_id_alt_05
FROM site_id_cd_result
GROUP BY site_id;
```